# Is there an equivalent method for getValueAt and setValueAt from jTable in spreadsheet controlsfx?

Tags: java, javafx, jtable, spreadsheet, controlsfx

I need to get and set value in the spreadsheet cell. I am wondering if there is any equivalent method for getValueAt and setValueAt from jTable in spreadsheet controlsfx? Or is there any other way.

Comment: The [`Grid`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/Grid.html)API includes an example.

Comment: For a given `row` and `column`, it looks like you can do something like this:  `SpreadsheetCell<?> cell = getRows().get(row).get(column)`.

Comment: @trashgod can you show an example implementation? For an instance, i need to put the value of the cell in a while loop to do stuff while it is empty.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API; look for a suitable property to learn when a cell is altered; `EDITABLE_EVENT_TYPE` looks promising.